# The argument type '_LoginScreenState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {}

AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 14), vsync: this);
```

Comment: A code dump is not a good question... please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Extending **SingleTickerProviderStateMixin** fixed the issue:

`class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{}`